# @WebMvcTest failing because is looking for mongoTemplate bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm trying to run the following test but it's failing because it tries to look for the `mongoTemplate bean` with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoTemplate' available
```

My understanding is that the `data` layer (or in this case the `MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class`) shouldn't be executed but it seems it is.

### The test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserDetailsController.class)
public class UserDetailsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void apisAreAccessibleIfAuthenticated() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user-details"))
                .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
    }

}
```

### The class under test

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailsController {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/user-details")
    public AppUser getUserDetails(Principal principal) {   
        return userRepository.findByUserName(principal.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Do you find a answer?

Comment: Do you have specific configurations on your SpringBootApplication class?

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51454688/2214203.

In short: Separate details' configuration from the configuration of the application's main class is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a mock for `UserRepository` but you are not implementing a stub for the `findByUserName` method. You should add something like this to your test before performing a get:

`Mockito.when(userRepository.findByUserName(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new AppUser());`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Without implementing a stub it will return null, which is ok for the test I'm running.