# A component required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found in JUnit 5 Controller Test

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, junit5, mongotemplate

I want to create a JUnit 5 controller integration test with in-memory MongoDB database. The problem occurs after tests running with error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

My Controller looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = DeviceController.class)
@EnableMongoRepositories
class DeviceControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private DeviceService deviceService;
}
```

I was trying to put:

```
excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class
```

or:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoConfiguration.class})
```

With configuration class like:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringMongoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("localhost"), "findall");
  }
}
```

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.interview</groupId>
  <artifactId>exercise</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>device</name>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mapstruct.processor.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.processor.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <spring.cloud.starter.netflix.hystrix.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</spring.cloud.starter.netflix.hystrix.version>
    <apache.common.lang.version>3.0</apache.common.lang.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${apache.common.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.cloud.starter.netflix.hystrix.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>

        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.processor.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>1.18.6</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>spring-boot-device-docker</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

I think that I checked every possible option and realy don't know what to do next to reach a goal. I will be grateful for advice on how to configure my test class for JUnit 5 controller test.

Comment: The question is confusing - on the one hand you want to use your in-memory Mongo instance, on the other - you are mocking the service (and MongoTemplate). Note that `@WebMvcTest` will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests. If you want full context, use `@SpringBootTest`.
On top of that, the controller code (and service code) can be useful for us to find the dependency problem

Comment: @Lesiak You right, I misunderstood how I suppose use MockBean in an integration test. Finally I did it like: 
`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = DeviceController.class)
class DeviceControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

  @MockBean
  private DeviceService deviceService;

  @MockBean
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
}` and it is working

Answer (score 2):

For unit Testing Controller class @MockBean is used for mocking the service layer or repository layer class or instance

The similar exception can occur when someone configured some configuration annotations such as

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {})
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
```

in main Spring Boot Application class, separating configurations to another class file helped me overcome the issue, as explained in the following thread

[@WebMvcTest not running due to missing dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453869/webmvctest-not-running-due-to-missing-dependency/51454688#51454688)